# Why Lemma 4.7 $\implies $ Corollary 4.8 ? Titchmarsh p74

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

This is from [p43 of Titchmarsh's.](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Titchmarsh_TheTheoryoftheRiemannZeta-Function.pdf)

> **Lemma 4.7:**  Let $f(x)$ be a real function with a continuous and steadily decreasing derivative $f'(x)$ in $(a,b)$ ( *I interpret this as $f'(x) \ge f'(y)$ if $x \ge y $* ) and let $f'(b) = \alpha$, $f'(a) = \beta.$ Then, 
>   $$ \sum_{a < n \le b } e^{2 \pi i f(n) } = \sum_{\alpha - \eta < \nu < \beta + \eta} \int_a^b e^{2 \pi i (f(x) - \nu x ) } \, dx  + O\{ \log (\beta - \alpha + 2 ) \}, $$ 
>   where $0< \eta < 1 $.
>
> **Corollary 4.8:**  Let $f(x)$ be real differentiable function in the interval $[a,b]$ and let $f'(x)$ be monotonic with $|f'(x)| \le \theta < 1$.  Then 
>   $$ \sum_{ a < n \le b } e^{ 2 \pi i f(n) } = \int_a^b e^{2 \pi i f(x) } \, dx + O(1). $$

**Q1: What I don't follow is why 4.8 is implied from 4.7 : $f'(x)$ can be increasing.**

I believe making the substitution $h(x)= f(b+a - x )$ does the trick. However, the proof of lemma 4.7 also holds if $f'$ is increasing (?) I worked through line by line and I don't see anything special of $f$ being decreasing.

> **Lemma 4.7':** Let $f(x)$ be a real function with a continuous and steadily increasing derivative $f'(x)$ in $(a,b)$, let $f(a) = \alpha$, $f'(b)= \beta$, then 
>   $$ \sum_{a < n \le b } e^{2 \pi i f(n) } = \sum_{\alpha - \eta < \nu < \beta + \eta} \int_a^b e^{2 \pi i (f(x) - \nu x ) } \, dx  + O\{ \log (\beta - \alpha + 2 ) \}, $$ 
>   where $0< \eta < 1 $.

Am I on the right track?